# How to input multiple arguments in a PyQt5 label?

Tags: python, pyqt5, label

I want to input multiple arguments (some text, and the variables `l_date` and `u_date` into a  `range_label` text label in PyQt5. My code is:

```
self.range_label.setText('Date range of data: ', l_date, '-', u_date)
```

However, this returns the error:

```
TypeError: setText(self, str): too many arguments
```

How do I input multiple arguments into a text label? Or should I be using another PyQt5 object?

Comment: `self.range_label.setText(f'Date range of data: {l_date} - {u_date}')`

Answer (score 0):

QLabel only accepts a single string so you must concatenate the string and for this Qt offers many ways but the simplest are the f-strings:

```py
text = f"Date range of data: {l_date} - {u_date}"
self.range_label.setText(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

As QLabel only accepts single string as argument. So, we can concatenate all the strings together or use f-string or directly can pass the argument.

Way 1 :

```
from datetime import date
today =  date.today()
l_date =  today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
u_date = today.strftime("%B %d, %Y")

#Main code
txt = "Date range of data: "+str(l_date)+" - "+str(u_date)
self.range_label.setText(txt)
```

Way 2:

```
txt = f"Date range of data: {l_date} - {u_date}"
self.range_label.setText(txt)
```

Way 3:

```
self.range_label.setText("Date range of data: "+str(l_date)+" - "+str(u_date))
```